# Is there a shortcut to run a suggested command in a terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, apt-get

If I type in a command for a program that is not installed I might get a message like this:

```
[user]~$ program
The program 'program' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install program
[user]~$
```

Is there a keyboard shortcut or command I can type that will execute `sudo apt-get install program` without me having to type it out myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an alias as appropriate for your shell. In `bash`, add this line to `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias sagi="sudo apt-get install"
```

Then, `source ~/.bashrc` and execute `alias` to verify the alias shows up in your list. After that, just type

```
sagi <package>
```

to invoke the alias. For other shells, the format of the alias command and the name of the rc file will be different, but the `source` and `alias` should be the same.

Comment: This seems like a simple and effective solution, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

If you are in a graphical terminal, triple-click in the line starting with `sudo apt-get` to mark it entirely and then middle-click to paste it into the terminal. Alternatively, judging from the output, typing something like

```
# $(program | tail -n 1)
```

to execute the output of `tail -n 1` command after being fed the output of `program`. This is probably not shorter. However, this should theoretically allow for the definition of an alias like the following

```
# alias ii='$( $(history -p !!) | tail -n 1)'
```

which should take the last command in the history, execute it, get its last line and execute it again. Unfortunately, this doesn’t work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609053/can-i-have-a-shell-alias-evaluate-a-history-substitution-command) discusses a similar problem but I didn’t quite manage to adapt it to this one, bash usually complains that it didn’t find `""`.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: It will now try to install /bin/*program*, /usr/bin/*program*, /sbin/*program*, or /usr/sbin/*program*.**

This is totally automatic...
Say you type in `g++ main.cpp` and you do not have g++ installed, it will ask if you want to install package g++, and if you answer yes, it will install it and then run `g++ main.cpp`.

(This is a one-time setup... Do this and you are good to go)

1. Install apt-file... `sudo apt-get install apt-file`
2. Update its cache... `sudo apt-file update`
3. Edit ~/.bashrc and add this to it:

   ```
   command_not_found_handle () {
   ask () {
     echo -ne "$1 (Y/n) ";
     read -N1 YES_ANSWER;
     echo "";
     YES_ANSWER=`echo $YES_ANSWER | sed 's/Y/y/; s/N/n/;'`;
     if [ "x$YES_ANSWER" == "xy" ]; then
       unset YES_ANSWER;
       return 0;
     elif [ "x$YES_ANSWER" == "xn" ]; then
       unset YES_ANSWER;
       return 1;
     elif [ "x$YES_ANSWER" == "x" ]; then
       unset YES_ANSWER;
       return 0;
     else
       ask_yes "$1";
       unset YES_ANSWER;
       return $?;
     fi;
   }
   if [ "x$1" == "x" ]; then
     echo "File name not provided.";
     return 1;
   fi;
   echo "Command not found: $1";
   echo "Searching for file in database...";
   FILE="`apt-file search /bin/$1 | sed 's/: /_/'`";
   if [ "x$FILE" != "x" ]; then
     FILE="`apt-file search /usr/bin/$1 | sed 's/: /_/'`";
   fi;
   if [ "x$FILE" != "x" ]; then
     FILE="`apt-file search /sbin/$1 | sed 's/: /_/'`";
   fi;
   if [ "x$FILE" != "x" ]; then
     FILE="`apt-file search /usr/sbin/$1 | sed 's/: /_/'`";
   fi;
   if [ "x$FILE" != "x" ]; then
     for f in "$FILE"; do
       if ask "\nDo you want to install package `echo $f | sed 's/_.*$//'` which provides `echo $f | sed 's/^.*_//'`?"; then
         sudo apt-get install `echo $f | sed 's/_.*$//'`;
         "$@";
         return $?;
       fi;
     done;
   else
     echo "Could not find file $1.";
     return 1;
   fi;
   }
   ```

I am still testing this, but in the preliminary test it seems to work. Every now and then it would be good to run `apt-file update` to refresh the list of available files.

To make the edited ~/.bashrc become effective, do one of the following:
log out and log back in again, or
run `. ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yum is only available for [RPM-based linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified).

Comment: @dafydd I realize that. I was just wishing that they did have yum, because of `yum provides`. It would make things easier.

Comment: If anybody sees something wrong with the above command, please leave a comment here telling me what is wrong. I just wrote the above a few minutes ago... Fixed about 4 bugs already... There is probably more yet... :(

Comment: +1  for the idea of replacing the `command_not_found_handle` handler.

Comment: @Zoredache The idea comes from Fedora... I did not like it, though, so I figured out what was happening and then disabled it. Now that knowledge came in handy to write some new code for Debian to do the same thing.